# jenkins deploying .war file to tomcat - TomcatManagerException

Tags: jenkins, tomcat8

Artifacts are being copied, but while deploying it to tomcat, the following exception is being thrown

```
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy
[/home/sherlock/.jenkins/workspace/My_Staging/MyApi.war]    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:106)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:184)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1047)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1025)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635) at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1819)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by:
org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException:
The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context
path [/MyGubbiApi] but context failed to start " instead of the
expected "OK" message
```

[image: DeployToStaging_Configuration]

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates your war was deployed, but failed to start. Check your tomcat logs for more detailed errors.

Also to verify this issue is not related to your Jenkins job configuration, could you verify whether manually deploying the war works? If manually deploying works, then the issue is likely in the Jenkins job configuration. If manual deployment fails (with same error), the problem can be found in the tomcat logs.

Comment: Even manual deployment fails. Actually I need to deploy two war files. I tried to give some context path in server.xml but still same error occurs.

Comment: Check the tomcat logs for more detailed error messages. The error message you showed only indicates an error occurred but not what error.